# Convert a selection in Android Autocomplete to a String

Tags: android, autocomplete

I have just implemented an autocompletion for a textfield using an online webservice, based on this answer on Stackoverflow:
[ArrayAdapter is updated late from Webservice in AutoCompleteTextAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546376/arrayadapter-is-updated-late-from-webservice-in-autocompletetextadapter)

Using an `ArrayAdapter<User> implements Filterable`, I have managed that the autocompletion suggests me entries as intended.
`User` is a Java Bean that contains information which is presented in the suggestion (age, name, ...).

When I select a suggestion, the Autocomplete field is filled with the 'wrong' data - using the `toString()`method, instead of the 'name' property of the bean.

My Question is: Can I override (in the Adapter) a method which will allow me to specify how to convert the bean so that the correct property is returned for the AutoCompleteTextView?
**(Ideally, User.toString() should not be changed)**

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found another way:

The method `convertSelectionToString(Object selectedItem)` in AutoCompleteTextView can be overridden by subclasses to allow for custom conversions. This way, no adjustment to the `toString()` method is required.

This - it seems to me - has the advantage that the Filter can return not just a list of Strings but a list of custom objects, which can be used by `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` of the adapter to construct "richer" suggestions.

The obvious disadvantage is that it requires subclassing AutoCompleteTextView for every Filterresult type whose toString() method shall not be modified.

```
@Override
protected CharSequence convertSelectionToString(Object selectedItem) {
    if(selectedItem instanceof User){
        User u = (User) selectedItem;
        return u.getUsername();
    } else {
        return super.convertSelectionToString(selectedItem);
    }
}
```

Any comments on this?

Comment: You can subclass AutoCompleteTextView and add a method
setCustomConvertSelectionToStringMethod() which takes an object (interface) with a custom "toString" method
In your convertSelectionToString method you check for the customMethod and execute if it's there...
This way you only have to subclass once

Answer (score 8):

There is no need subclassing `AutoCompleteTextView`and override the `convertSelectionToString`method. The same thing is achievable by overriding the [`convertResultToString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#convertResultToString(java.lang.Object))method in your custom `Filter` in (your already subclassed) `ArrayAdapter`.

I had the same problem: custom objects in my `ArrayAdapter` whose `toString()` implementation wasn't something I could control. I implemented the method like this:

```
// In custom Filter implementation

@Override
public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object result) {
   if(result instanceof MyCustomClass) {
      return ((MyCustomClass) result).getAttribute("name");
   }

   return super.convertResultToString(result);
}
```

Comment: Should be selected as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The search results depend on what the data's `toString()` returns. In your case you need to return `name` field in the `toString()` implementation.

Comment: Yes, that occurred to me too, however I'd like to know whether there is a method in the Adapter or another place (except toString of the bean) that I can override instead.

Comment: Yes. You can do a direct comparison of the `constraint` with name field in `performFiltering` method of the `Filter`  class.

Answer (score 2):

If you subclass your own adapter from `SimpleCursorAdapter`, you can set a `CursorToStringConverter` on the Adapter in the constructor.

```
private class AutoCompleteAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);

        /* Other setup code here  */

        setCursorToStringConverter(new CursorToStringConverter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor item) {
                return item.getString(item.getColumnIndex(DESIRED_COLUMN_NAME));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case I don't use a database - but I'll certainly keep it in mind for the future! Thanks!